# online tool to calculate md5

Tags: md5

Is there a online tool which can calculate the md5 sum of a certain document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm

Comment: http://www.md5online.info MD5 for largn files

Answer (score 0):

http://hashfor.me

Though for reference, I built this.